# Is there a __LINE__ macro for GAS assembly that expands to the current source line number?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

Like in NASM and C.

Simply preprocessing it with `cpp` does not work since I want to define a macro like:

```
.macro ASSERT_FAIL
    mov __LINE__, %eax
    call assert_fail
.endmacro
```

which expands the `__LINE__` whenever `ASSERT_FAIL` is used so I can see where the failure happened. So `__LINE__` must be expanded after `ASSERT_FAIL`.

I would also like to put that macro in a separate file and include it with `.include`.

I have been able to achieve exactly that with NASM:

```
%macro ASSERT_FAIL 0
    mov eax, __LINE__
    call assert_fail
%endmacro
```

Is there any alternative besides using `cpp`'s `#include` and `#define` instead of `.macro` and `.include`? The manual [does say that](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/as/Preprocessing.html#Preprocessing) there are little built-in pre-processing power in `gas`. It makes me wonder why `.macro` and `.include` exist at all if they are so limited.

EDIT: I have examined the kernel and glibc. glibc does not have a single `.include` and very few `.macro`. The kernel has no `.include`, but uses a mixture of both `.macro` and `#define`, with a tendency of leaving `.macro` for multi-line macros as it is more readable.

Comment: Use `#define ASSERT_FAIL` like in C.

Comment: @RossRidge I would also need to use `cpp`'s `#include` instead of `.include`. Makes me wonder why `.macro` and `.include` exist at all. It is true that https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/as/Preprocessing.html#Preprocessing basically says: use CPP.

Comment: Sure, but your #include file can .include the rest if you want. The assembly macro stuff is there because other assemblers have it, but its never been considered an important part of the assembler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by `@RossRidge`, the best solution I could find so far was to use cpp and use:

```
#define ASSERT_FAIL \
    mov $__LINE__, %eax ;\
    call assert_fail
```

This also requires any macro that use this to use CPP and not `.macro`, and `#include` and not `.include`. So the best thing to do is to use only `cpp` for macros everywhere.

If you use the standard `.S` (uppercase) extension, `gcc` 4.8 automatically runs `cpp` by default, which is convenient.

But if your use case is a bit different, make sure to explore other GCC features. For example, I was also considering using `__LINE__` to generate unique local labels, but then I found the [numeric local relative labels](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html) which were a much better option.